# Matlab plot: line is not smooth

Tags: plot, matlab-figure

I use Matlab on an Osx retina display.

When I plot points (or a line, like a function), the points (or the line) are not smooth, no matter which size for the x-step I choose.

But when I try to resize manually the figure window (when the plot changes its dimensions on the screen), the points (or the line) instantaneously become smoother and better defined.

Does anyone know how can I obtain a smooth plot without resizing the figure window ?
Thanks

Comment: can you show an example of this happening? it doesn't happen when i plot.

Comment: Here is the line plotted by Matlab: [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/296ddtz.png[/IMG]

and here is the line when I resize the figure window: 
[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2ahs6et.png[/IMG]

Comment: In the matlab interface does everything look like it's scaled correctly? Or do the buttons and text look too big or too small. I mean this compared to othe apple software.

Comment: No, in the Matlab interface everything is scaled correctly.

Comment: try adding this to your code after `imshow` and after any other things related tot he plot like title. `drawnow; jFig = get(handle(gcf), 'JavaFrame'); jFig.setMaximized(true);` it will automatically make the window full size.